# How to make a block of code highlight in one note?

Tags: plugins, codeblocks, highlight, onenote

How to make a block of code highlight in one note ? and is there a plugin which can help me ?

Answer (score 8):

This is not my original post but i taught sharing would help others :)

To add the code block in ms one note you need to add additional package (again this is not my original work I am just writing this tutorial.)

Open below link and download the relevant packages as per your OS Architect and install.

https://github.com/elvirbrk/NoteHighlight2016/releases

and install the package and restart the ms one note and you can see new tab in your ms one note.
[image]

[image]

select your type of code.

[image]

and you're done.
But please don't report bugs here i am not the owner of the project.

And the code doesn't gets posted where the curser present rather it gets posted in top the one note text box.

Comment: Awesome....Worked with OneNote 2016